# Как использовать тип DOUBLE в моем случае?

Tags: mysql

В таблицу изначально должно писаться два числа типа `int(11)` с разными названиями. Например, 984512 и 856214.

Чтобы не использовать два запроса `SELECT`, решил записать эти числа через точку, как `984512.856214` а в таблице создать одно поле типа `DOUBLE`, и при получении числа разделять его на два по точке с помощью PHP.

Мне не совсем понятно как работает тип `DOUBLE` и нужно быть уверенным, что данные не будут округляться и непредсказуемо обрезаться.

**1.** Какие максимально допустимые значения числа для левой стороны (т.е. до точки) и какие для правой в этом типе?
**2.** Как правильно задать в структуре таблицы тип `DOUBLE`, то есть вот эту строку:

```
`num_1` int(11) NOT NULL,          было так
`num_2` int(11) NOT NULL,          было так
`num_1` double(21) NOT NULL,       нужно вот так, смущает кол-во символов 21, правильно ли?
```

чтобы и левая и правая часть обрезались одинаково, в случае когда длина числа превысит допустимое значение?
`12345.123 - недопустимо`
`123.123 - допустимо`
`99811444.77455999 - допустимо`

**3.** В верном ли направлении мыслю вообще?

Comment: Оставь в покое два int'а. И какие ещё 2 запроса? о_О

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего будет достаточно `union`:

SQL:

```
select num from table where id = 1
union all
select num from table where id = 2
```

PHP:

```
$row=$result->fetch_row();
echo $row[0]; // для id = 1
$row=$result->fetch_row();
echo $row[0]; // для id = 2
```

Comment: Я нашел топикастера в чате  и выяснил у него оригинальную проблему, которую он пытался решить - выбрать две строки, с разными условиями, строку с первым условием - первой.

Comment: это ради этого он писал два int в float???

Answer (score 9):

> В таблицу изначально должно писаться два числа типа int(11) с разными названиями. Например, 984512 и 856214.

Это значит, что туда и должно писаться два числа integer. Вы таким подходом нарушаете саму семантику, у вас почему-то данные типа А записываются в составе типа Б - вы ни выбрать их нормально не можете, ни поиск по ним сделать (представьте, как будет выглядеть запрос с условием `WHERE A1 > 30000 AND A2 > 30000` при текущей структуре БД).

Кроме того, ваш подход неизбежно приводит к потере данных. Вы можете почитать про внутреннее устройство [чисел с плавающей запятой](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9) - они очень ненадежны с точки зрения хранения конкретной величины. И подобная запись

> ```
> `num_1` double(21) NOT NULL, нужно вот так, смущает кол-во символов 21, правильно ли?
> ```

отвечает вовсе не за символы, а за [количество бит](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html) в мантиссе такого числа (причем, насколько понимаю - в мануале это явно не указано - на самом деле там всего два типа точности, 32бит или 64бит).

Резюмируя - вы больше сложностей себе наберете, используя такой подход, я не только выступаю против него, но и не буду ничего говорить о том, как с ним жить.

Comment: Да, double ненадежны и в этом суть.

Comment: Эти два числа всегда достаются из БД вместе. Сейчас используются запросы:
`SELECT num_1 и 
SELECT num_2`

Почему бы не реализовать `SELECT num`, после
`<?php
$num = explode(".", $row[0]);
echo $num[0]; // первое число
echo $num[1]; // второе число
?>`

Если это нельзя сделать с помощью `DOUBLE` типа, то можно реализовать с `VARCHAR`.

Мне нужно понять всего лишь какой тип данных надежнее использовать.

Comment: @koji два int. Если у вас такие беспокойства из-за единичности селекта, то доставайте, как `SELECT num_1, num_2`.

Comment: неправильно выразил запрос - `SELECT * FROM table WHERE num_1 и SELECT * FROM table WHERE num_2`, в этом случае не получится выборка `SELECT num_1, num_2`. Как вариант вижу использование `DOUBLE` до 15 символов либо `VARCHAR` с записью `число.число` Это статистические данные и они будут только извлекаться по `id`, без поиска и других манипуляций с числами.

Comment: @koji, вы в курсе, что существуют операторы OR и AND?

Answer (score 5):

Вы пытаетесь встроить базу данных в базу данных: в каждой ячейке у вас появляется таблица из двух целых чисел. Причем вам нужно придумать свой язык запросов для этой микробазы и формат хранения, как уже говорилось тут, ненадежный.

Как использовать тип double- никак. Используйте два int. Оптимизируйте только тогда, когда в этом есть необходимость.

Answer (score -2):

Используй `DECIMAL(precision, scale)` type.

Answer (score -5):

В приведенном случае было решено использовать, в структуре таблицы, тип `VARCHAR`, как наиболее предсказуемый с точки зрения полного сохранения цифр в числе (т.е. без округления). Выборка осуществляется по `ID` типа `int(11)`, что никоим образом не скажется на скорости выборки записав число в поле текстового типа. 
VARCHAR позволит хранить числа разделяя их символом, например точкой или слешем, а после выборки разделять число на два посредством php-функции `explode()`

запись содержащаяся в таблице: `85645.98256`

```
    <?php
        // запрос к БД
        $mysqli->query("SELECT num FROM table WHERE id=2");
        $row=$result->fetch_row();

        // получение 2-ух чисел из одного поля таблицы
        $num = explode(".", $row[0]);
        echo $num[0]; // первое число 85645
        echo $num[1]; // второе число 98256
     ?>
```

Comment: Ужасное решение. Вы всё же выясните, как именно хранятся числа внутри, и поймите, что хранение _десятичных_ разрядов не гарантируются. Кроме того, ваша база не находится даже в первой нормальной форме.

Comment: @koji зачем?? чем вас не устроило решение с одним запросом `SELECT num1, num2 FROM table WHERE id=2` и доставанием результатов через `$row[0]` и `$row[1]`?

Comment: @koji вы же в курсе, что можно выбрать две колонки одним запросом. а не только конкретную колонку или `*`?

Comment: @PashaPash, потому, что нельзя выбрать `SELECT num1, num2` так как у `num1 — ID=1` а у `num2 — ID=2` как я могу выбрать если ID различны? Это невозможно.

Comment: @koji так сформулируйте нормально проблему в самом вопросе. как ваш код ее решает - да точно так же, никак - вы же тоже выбираете только для одного id = 2.

Comment: @PashaPash, возможно не в курсе наведите пример! есть две клонки, первая имеет `id=1, значение num1=130` вторая имеет `id=2, значение num2=150`

Comment: @koji ваш код в "ответе" не выбирает `id=1, значение num1=130`. он вообще не выбирает данные для строки с `id=1`. он выбирает num1 и num2 для строки с id = 2

Comment: @koji т.е. он полностью эквивалентен коду их моего комментария выше.

Comment: @PashaPash, все верно, потому что теперь там только одно поле `num` вместо `num1 и num2`, которое теперь хранит в себе два числа из этих двух полей (то есть из полей num1 и num2), и, соответственно, id теперь только один и его значение равно 2. Вместо того чтобы выбирать по двум id (то есть id=1 и id=2) я выбираю по одному id, а после полученное значение разделяю посредством php на два нужных мне числа по точке.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25288/discussion-between-pashapash-and-koji).